# How to update without overwriting children?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

consider this existing data in a Firebase Realtime Database

```
db.ref('path/to/child').once('value')

{
  "data":{
    "this":"value",
    "that":"value"
  }
}
```

consider this set operation to the original data

```
db.ref('path/to/child').update({"data":{"this":"newValue"}})

{
  "data":{
    "this":"newValue",
  }
}
```

how do we perform an update so that the unchanged data is preserved

```
db.ref('path/to/child').foo({"data":{"this":"newValue"}})

{
  "data":{
    "this":"newValue",
    "that":"value"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, your code is telling Firebase to update the **entire** `data` child under `path/to/child`.  Instead, you should reference the most deep path to the final child node you want to update:

```
db.ref('path/to/child/data').update({"this":"newValue"})
```

Note that I've put `data` in the reference, instead of the object to update.

Comment: sounds like I will have to iterate over the object and update each item individually?

Comment: If all the things you want to update are not all sibling children to each other, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the example above didnt work. I came to the same conclusion based on the docs which also didn't work. It still overwrote the content in "data".

Testing with a slash after data (in my case the object key) worked for me. Maybe I'm still misunderstanding something about how this works, but thought I'd add this incase anyone else hit the same issue. If I'm wrong, please explain.

This did work exactly as I expected.

```
db.rev('path/to/child/data/').update({"this": "newValue")
// almost exact path I use on some random test data
// path -> root/userid/list/listid/

db.rev('user/2FsJBrxZHQFff61QkMIuTV49KBUcQ2/list/MOwh_FwDmlKbxsfUmZS/').update({"name": "newValue")
```